# Elixir - How can I connect to a TCP? :gen_tcp is giving me trouble

Tags: elixir, gen-server, gen-tcp

I have Vowpal Wabbit server running at a certain IP and on a certain port. I can interact with it from the command line as follows:

```
echo "|c country_US" | nc 10.228.14.116 26542
0.512143    <-- this is the response
```

On the other hand, if I don't pipe any info to netcat, it behaves as follows:

```
nc 10.228.14.116 26542  <-- just waits forever
```

This is expected and correct behavior for my Vowpal Wabbit setup. Now I just need to talk to Vowpal Wabbit via TCP from Elixir.

From within IEX:

```
opts = [:binary, active: false]
{:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect({10, 228, 14, 116}, 26542, opts)
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :etimedout}
```

So my question is: Given that my service is running correctly and responding on TCP, how can I connect to it using :gen_tcp?

I'm trying to follow the guide [here](http://andrealeopardi.com/posts/handling-tcp-connections-in-elixir/).

**UPDATE** False alarm -- I just had a typo in my code.

Comment: Are you sure the counterpart is not UDP? For UDP one should use [`:gen_udp`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html).

Comment: `nc` without `-u` will use TCP, so it's probably not UDP. I don't see anything wrong with the code though... it should be working. @jonomono do you get that error instantly or after a while?

Comment: @Dogbert the `{:error, :etimedout}` response from elixir takes about 10 seconds or so - not instant.